# Boostsrap Validation reset form validation Icon not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am using bootstrap validation plugin for form validaiton.

1. When I click on the 'Cancel' button without changing any values of form field, it should close the  page and take me to page where I was before visiting this page.
2. I cleared couple of fields  and clicked on Cancel button. The old values reseted but it still shows the validation error.

Html Code:

```
<form class="profile_settings" id="profile_settings" data-toggle="validator" role="form">

    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <input type="text" required="required" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control firstname input-lg input-border first_name input-style" placeholder="First name"  value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
        <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="form-control lastname input-lg input-border last_name input-style" placeholder="Last name" value="">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="profile-save-btn" style="padding-left: 37px;"><img src="images/savetick.png"><span class="profile-save green-separator">Save</span>
    </button>
    <button type="reset" class="profile-cancel-btn"><img src="images/cancel.png"><span class="profile-cancel">Cancel</span>
    </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Js code:

```
<script>
    $("#profile_settings").bootstrapValidator({
        message : 'This value is not valid',
        container : 'tooltip',
        feedbackIcons : {
            valid : 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid : 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating : 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields : {
            first_name : {
                container : 'popover',
                validators : {
                    notEmpty : {
                        message : 'First name is required and cannot be empty'
                    },
                    regexp : {
                        regexp : /^[a-z\s]+$/i,
                        message : 'First name can only consist of alphabetical characters'
                    },
                    stringLength : {
                        min : 3,
                        message : 'first name must be more than 3 characters '
                    }

                }

            },
            last_name : {
                container : 'popover',
                validators : {
                    notEmpty : {
                        message : 'Last name is required and cannot be empty'
                    },
                    regexp : {
                        regexp : /^[a-z\s]+$/i,
                        message : 'Last name can only consist of alphabetical characters'
                    },
                    stringLength : {
                        min : 3,
                        message : 'Last name must be more than 3 characters '
                    }

                }

            },

        }
    }).on('success.form.bv', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        profileInfoSubmit(this);

    });
    });
$('.profile-cancel-btn').click(function() {
   var previousUrl = document.referrer;
   //window.location=previousUrl;


});

</script>
```

## 1.When click the cancel button -  How I can i find the form values are changed or not? If changed means reset the form values otherwise i need to redirect the page previous visited page url.

## 2. When i click the cancel(reset) button the values are reseted but the validation icon(error x mark) not reseted.

Please suggest me the way.

Comment: You should call [`resetForm`](http://formvalidation.io/api/#reset-form) method when clicking the cancel(reset) button

Comment: resetForm does not work.  Any other ideas?